# Maximum Probability - Explanation

Tags: probability

You are writing a program that counts the relative frequency with which certain words appear in queries
that Mozilla searchers have used (for this you have been given access to Mozilla search logs). Based on
your program’s output, the word ‘London’ appears with a relative frequency of 0.5 and the word ‘Landmarks’
with relative frequency 0.3

Note:  assume that words occur independently of each other (they dont effect each others probability of occuring)

q) What is the maximum probability that a randomly chosen query from your sample will contain
the exact phrase "London Landmarks"?

P
(
A
∩
B
)
?

P(AnB)= P(A)P(B)

P(AnB)=0.5*0.3

P(AnB)=0.15
I don’t know how to explain why is this the maximum probability ?

The only way I can think of is that this is the maximum because if we were to repeat the experiment infinitely this the highest frequency possible that they would overlap

Comment: This is not the maximum probability. It is the only valid probabiliy, if A and B are independent: $P(A\cap B)=P(A)\cdot P(B)=0.5 \cdot 0.3=0.15$

Comment: Then what would be the maximum ? As it cannot be higher than 1

Comment: "Maximum probability" doesn't make sense for this scenario as described.

Comment: @RoboJumble You said that the events are independent. If this is the case, then there is only one valid value. It would be another case, if it is not given whether the events are independent or not.

Comment: I fail to see what you mean by maximum probability... Can you give more context?

Comment: @RiezFrechetKolmogorov thats what the questions says nothing more

Comment: I doubt that this is the exact wording of the question since it is not grammatical English. If you provide the correct version we may be able to help.

Comment: @EthanBolker thats the exact wording

Comment: The new wording is a completely different question - not at all what you started with. This version says nothing about independence. @grand_chat has answered the correct version. (I suspect that though you corrected the question you did not correct the possible answers to choose from.)

Comment: @callculus42 I think that’s what the question is asking why is that the maximum ? As you said since they are independent the only possible value to get their intersection would be by multiplying their probability

Answer (score 3):

There may be two questions here: (1) what is the maximum value of $P(A\cap B)$ with no additional assumptions on $A$ and $B$, and (2) what is the value of $P(A\cap B)$ if $A$ and $B$ are independent.

You've already found the answer to (2). For (1), notice that $P(A\cap B)\le P(A)$ since $A\cap B\subset A$. So $P(A\cap B)\le 0.5$. Similarly, $P(A\cap B)\le P(B)=0.3$. So an upper bound on $P(A\cap B)$ is $0.3$. This upper bound is in fact achievable: if it happens that $B\subset A$, then $A\cap B=B$. (This would be the case if every occurrence of "landmarks" appears next to "London", i.e., the word  "landmarks" isn't seen except when paired with "London".) So the maximum possible value for $P(A\cap B)$ is $0.3$.

Comment: (2) is the question as they have told us that occurance of A and B are independent however i am struggling to understand why that is the maximum probability ?

Comment: Your edited version of the question says nothing about independence. This answer is correct for (1), which is what you have been asked about.

Comment: @EthanBolker the fact that they are independent is written in the question

Comment: You edited the question to ADD that note about independence after I asked you twice to post the whole question.